# Wordpress + Bootstrap 3 + responsive thumbnail grid

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a Wordpress theme basically from scratch (used a very basic theme as a starter but changing all the files) I am importing/using the bootstrap3 CDN framework.

I've got the nav and header footer setup done, but I'm relatively new to wordpress theme making and all I want on the index.php is a responsive grid of thumbnails that are the featured images of my posts.

I've looked for tuts/examples but none seem to have both bootstrap and wordpress. Only describe one or the other. Is there any good tuts to accomplish this task?

- cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't help you with the tut, but if you want to create a responsive thumbnail grid in index.php. Then it is easy. As for bootstrap you have to know about the grid system. you can find it [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

And as for showing your featured images as a thumbnail you can use

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

You can find all the details in [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Hope this helps you to find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help per say with your problem, but did recently watch this tut "[Getting first wordpress website up](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/getting-first-wordpress-website-up)" on pluralsight (which unfortunately isn't free) which has a whole section on searching for and installing both new Plugins and Themes. Helped me out. Good luck and don't give up

Comment: thanks for the link, I am familiar with plugins etc, and youtube has tons just not what i'm looking for. A company that has done a beautify job at what I'm looking for is on their 'work' page    - http://redantler.com/work/